# Load json file in js code from another folder in Django app

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I'm developing a Django app, and I'm using intro.js to create a guided tour within one of my views. I currently load the tour steps from a JSON file located in the same folder as my JavaScript files (`/static/js/stepsTours.json`).

```
function quickStartTurotial() {

    fetch('/static/js/stepsTours.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            jsonData = data;
            let steps = [];
            // Load steps for the selected tour
            if (jsonData["quick-start"]) {
                steps = jsonData["quick-start"];
            }
            // Start the tutorial
            if (steps.length > 0) {
                const intro = introJs()
                    .setOptions({
                        steps: steps,
                        showProgress: true,
                        showBullets: false,
                        disableInteraction: true,
                    });
                intro.start();
            } else {
                console.log("No steps found");
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error loading JSON file:', error));
}
```

However, I'd like to move this JSON file to a different folder, specifically a "config" folder as shown below:

[image]

My Django app is named "validator". When I change the path in the fetch request to `fetch('/config/stepsTours.json')`, I encounter the following error:

[image]

The view in the browser looks like this:

[image]

How can I correctly configure the path to load the JSON file from the "config" folder? I have to configure some url in my Django app?

Answer (score 1):

Did you define 'config' folder in **settings.py**? Looks like you are misunderstanding how static files works in django.

If you want to use 'config' folder for static files you should define it in **settings.py**. For example you can try implement mupltiple dirs for static files:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    BASE_DIR / "config",
]
```

There could be a better aproach for your case. So I advise you to take a deeper look at [offical docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/).

Comment: This solved my problem on my local pc, but when I deploy this on amazon ec2 instance i got `tutorial.js:87 Error loading JSON file: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`, so the js code could not open file from config folder

Comment: Did you try 'python manage.py collectstatic' ?